# Excel vba: .ZOrder-property does not change the order of the shapes in the "Selection pane"

Tags: excel, vba, shapes, z-order

**I was wondering if anyone could answer why the change of .ZOrder-property does not change the order of the shapes in the "Selection pane"** (see first picture).

Luckily for me, the code works as intended, where things are reorganized to be displayed as the order given prior to running the code. (See code in the bottom).
This code is needed as the code groups and ungroups some chartobjects which first have a user-defined order, but during the grouping-action the charts become chronologically listed, then I have made a code that rearranges the single charts back to the original order when ungrouped again.

Regards Hallvard

[image: Selection pane]

[image: Code that is rearranging shapes]

Comment: Could you post the code instead of the screenshot, so it's easier to reproduce?

Comment: Not that I gave a second look at the screenshot, all those charts are hidden, that is the reason they are not moving I'd say.

Comment: Ah, its a huge code, and these are only parts of it. The only things missing from the code related the question is that arrChrtObjectsZOrder is first called in the start of the code to get the original ZOrders of the charts. arrChrtToEdtNams is an array with chart names "= Array ("Chart 10", ...). The code works as intended, but the order in the selection pane does not change, only the Order of which they are shown (ZOrder). So the question should maybe be rephrased to "Why is the ZOrder-property and the Selection Pane order not linked/connected? Which property is then listedin selection pane"